# dynamicly send the parameter to a table on click of a word in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I am very new to SSRS. I am creating a report. 
I am trying to display a table on click of a word(on left side of the page) in the report, which is passed as the parameter to the generate the table(right side of the page).

Can some body help me on how to so this.

Note: the click-able word is with in the text box. 
And also i want to avoid using another report as i wnat the table to be displayed on the same page as the clicked word.

Comment: can anybody help on this.. ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I would do. On your texbox. Go to action, choose go to report and choose the report itself. Then you can send the value of your textbox as a parameter to the report itself. See images below. You can get the value of your textbox by using =ReportItems![Textbox1].Value. Change Textbox1 to what your texbox is called. When you press the textbox now your report will refresh and you can use the parameter to f.ex filter your data or anything you need it for.

Create parameter

[image: Create Parameter]

Add action and send textbox value to your report

[image: Add action and send textbox value to your report]

Before action

[image: Before action]

After action

[image: After action]

Comment: Its a creative solution. Not very clean, but it's not our fault that clients ask specific that some tools can't do right?